# Editing Theme Files on Wordpress.com-hosted Site

Tags: php, themes, wordpress.com-hosting

I'm doing some work for a client on her Wordpress.com-hosted site. I'm used to only working on self-hosted WP sites, and I know how to edit the theme files there, but I'm not sure if it is possible to do this on a Wordpress.com-hosted site.

I'm trying to change the way that blog posts are displayed when listing posts from a given category, which I would usually do by going into the theme and editing the relevant php file. Is this not possible with this type of site?

Thanks!

Comment: wordpress.com customizations are off topic here. Please ask their support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With WordPress.com you can edit a theme's CSS styles**, fonts**, or other display options offered under the theme's Appearance->Customize menu.  You do not have access to edit any of the theme's php or template files.

**notes premium feature